# How I large the Font Size of Auto Complete Custom Source Text box Vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, text, box

I have the below code but not working i want to change the text box font name and font size auto complete custom source

```
      Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Item_Urdu FROM table_33", cn)
    Dim ds As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    da.Fill(ds)
    For i = 0 To ds.Rows.Count - 1
        col.Add(ds.Rows(i)("Item_Urdu").ToString())
    Next
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold)
```

Comment: The standard [IAutoComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nn-shldisp-iautocomplete) interface doesn't provide any option to change the Font of the AutoComplete popup. You can always implement your own. Or (though kind of a long shot), you could use the AutoCompleteBox control (part of the `WPF Toolkit` NuGet package) through WPF Interop. This control does allow to set the Font style of the popup, plus other personalizations. (Please, remove this thing: `TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold)`)

Comment: How i Can do please post the code here